# Strange unusable items in Camp McCarran (Get your flint on)

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

In Camp McCarran, along with other areas of the wasteland, I have found "named" items (those which have a name when the cursor is above them) which can not be interacted with.

The latest example is the Flint with accompanying Welding Gun in Camp McCarran.  Do these have any known uses?  Are they cut content?  Are they part of a quest and only become usable later?

I am tormented by these fiendish uninteractable devils.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the wiki, the [Flint](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Flint_%28Fallout:_New_Vegas%29) and the [Welding gun](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Welding_gun) are indeed uninteractable and cannot even be picked up. There's no information if they were to be used for crafting or any other way. No marked quest in the game uses them up to this moment. They could become crafting items if future DLC packs add more crafting recipes and make them usable, but until now, with Dead Money and Honest Hearts, that hasn't happened yet.

Answer (score 1):

There's a mod on FNV Nexus that allows you to use welding guns as crafting stations. The mod is an alternative repairer and the welding guns are used to make armour plating to repair heavy armour. That is the only way (using a mod) I have seen you be able to use these items.

Comment: Could you link to that mod's page at the FNV Nexus?

Answer (score 0):

they are just misc items to populate the world and give it depth.  In fallout 3 you could shoot junk items like that out of the Rock It launcher, but I cannot remember if they have that gun or an equivalent in this game.

Comment: No no, one can not even pick these things up.

Answer (score -1):

I reckon it's just dirt, by which I mean the stuff the builders/programmers left in the game at an early stage and didn't see the need to get rid of due to time constraints...deadlines make for sweeping decisions and sometimes performance or content issues will arise, like the memory issue when FNV was first released. The solution was simple enough, but not knowing the solution sent quite a few people into a tailspin. Y'know, denouncing the game as a failure and so on. I've enjoyed F3 and FNV immensely and actually enjoy some of the more random elements of these games, in that you can play them out several times without duplicating your outcomes, but also just have fun enjoying the feel of the game, immersing yourself in it's idiosyncrasies...one thing does bug me a little though...the music. I'd be interested to hear from others what kind of music they'd like to hear in the Fallout universe.

Comment: Hi Elmer, welcome to the site. Regarding your music remark. This is a question and answers site that focusses on answerable questions that are not subjective. Ingame music is opinion and thus not really something SE cares about. Also that is more a forum question. As you have noted, this isn't a forum. Enjoy your stay!